# What is happening when converting PIL objects to numpy?

Tags: numpy, optimization, python-imaging-library

I am creating a big numpy array with [n_images, width, height, 3].
To do that I create an empty list and append numpy arrays created from cropping RGB images and converting them to numpy arrays.

I came across something really strange trying to optimize my code:

```
import time
from PIL import Image

im1=Image.open("random_png_image.png")
im2=Image.open("random_png_image.png").convert('RGB')

t1=time.time()
a1=np.asarray(im1)
t2=time.time()
a2=np.asarray(im2)
t3=time.time()

print("Converting to numpy without converting to RGB mode first took: %0,3f ms"%((t2-t1)*1000.0))
print("Converting to numpy after the image was converted to RGB first took: %0,3f ms"%((t3-t2)*1000.0))
```

And I get a HUUUGE difference:

- around 80ms for the first op
- around 8ms for the second

Why is that ? Is PIL implicitly doing this convert_to_rgb when converting it to a numpy array ? Both PIL objects if inspected have RGB mode so it is weird. Is there a way to accelerate the process ? What should I do to optimize this process ? Not use PIL ? Convert them to array afterwards ?

Comment: You might want to have a look into scikit-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation for `Image.open`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.open):

> Opens and identifies the given image file. **This is a lazy operation**;
>   the function reads the file header, but **the actual image data is not
>   read from the file until you try to process the data**

With the first operation, you're timing the process of reading the data from disk.

Comment: Yeah I figured it was something like that, do you know if it is possible to lower that time somehow a fast_load function from PIL or whatever?

Comment: @jean: Buy a faster disk? You're not going to improve your disk performance in software. If you're reading things from disk more times than you need to, you could try to cut down on that, but there's no "fast_load" function that just makes the disk faster somehow.

Comment: Ok, too bad  ! Thanks !